who is this mysterious device owner? how do I disable it?
I can't set a device owner on the xiomi duoqin f22. (you can call it "device owner" or "profile owner" etc.)
i tried all methods previously given like ejecting sim card, hard reset, removed all accounts etc.
searched the whole internet for some other way around. couldn't find anything really helpful.
this is how the conversation looks.
adb shell "dpm set-device-owner com.com.babor/com.com.babor.AdminReciever

Exception occurred while executing 'set-device-owner':
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to set the device owner, but the user already has a profile owner.
        at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.enforceCanSetDeviceOwnerLocked(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:9409)
        at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.setDeviceOwner(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:8352)
        at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerServiceShellCommand.runSetDeviceOwner(DevicePolicyManagerServiceShellCommand.java:256)
        at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerServiceShellCommand.onCommand(DevicePolicyManagerServiceShellCommand.java:89)
        at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)
        at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)
        at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.onShellCommand(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:9728)
        at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:950)
        at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:834)
        at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub.onTransact(IDevicePolicyManager.java:6952)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1184)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1143)

does anybody have a way to fix this?  thanks

And what is the package name of the device owner? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66157371/295004
